# Find what a phrase with removed letters originally said in fewest characters

Tags: code-golf, string

Write a program that, given a string of capital letters, output all possible phrases that could have been written originally, using any variant of the Oxford English Dictionary.

### Input

There are two inputs:

- A string \$s\$ of A-Z capital letters that is a phrase with certain letters removed. Example: `THSSANEAMPLE`
- Another string \$r\$ of the letters that have been removed from said phrase. Example: `IX`. These letters are in no particular order.

### Output

Output all phrases shorter than twice the length of \$s\$ which, after removing letters in \$r\$, result in \$s\$. Separate words in each phrase by spaces.

### Rules

- You are allowed to access any webpage you want, as long as it was created before this question was originally asked. If this webpage was changed in order to facilitate this challenge, then this is likewise not acceptable.
- Slang or names of places or people are not required.
- Disregard whether a phrase would be syntactically or grammatically correct.
- Assume that any full word containing only omitted letters is not to be included.

### Examples

"MITURE","X" should only have one possibility.

"MN", "DAI" should give you "MAN", but need not give "ADMIN", "MIND", or "DAMN" because they're at least twice as long as "MN".

Comment: I would recommend providing a specific dictionary for the programs to use. Otherwise different programs could end up working with different specifications.

Comment: "You are allowed to access any website you want, as long as it was created before this question was originally asked" - This still leaves the possibility of a website being created before this challenge, but updated afterwards. Also websites can change, breaking answers that were previously working. It's up to you what to allow, but allowing accessing websites can make it more difficult to write the spec in a robust way. If you're interested in alternative approaches, one way would be to specify a dictionary file and say "you may access this file" rather than a website.

Comment: Did my best to interpret, but I'm not sure (a) if the letters in `r` are a set or in some order, (b) whether we can output each phrase as a list of words. The dictionary issue mentioned above also needs fixing, especially since many languages have builtin English dictionaries that may or may not be "generally reputable".

Comment: It is also reasonable to specify that the answer can use any dictionary, as long as an arbitrary different dictionary can be substituted in the same number of bytes to load it, such as by taking the dictionary as a third parameter or loading it from a file.

Comment: Can you assume that you can not add full words to the phrase (if letter I is missing I can't just add the word I everywhere)?

Comment: While we have closed your question it is just because we think that it needs a bit more clarification before it is ready. I do think that it can be a very interesting challenge.

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk I have edited the question to fit criticism.

Comment: I found 160 possible solutions to your example. You might want to add an example with fewer solutions so that you can give people some input output pairs to test with. Solution: (this) (is/six) (an/((a/ax) nix)) (example/(exam pile/(pi (lie/lex)))/(ex ample/(amp (lie/lex))/(am/aim/((a/ax) mix) (pile/(pi (lie/lex)))

Comment: What constitutes slang?

Comment: @PostLeftGarfHunter Words created in the last 10 years or so or are in not common usage that tend to be used more frequently in speech than writing, or profanities.

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk My example was just to demonstrate what I meant, but I'll add another one.

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk Is the challenge acceptable now

Comment: Two questions: **1) Why websites?** Not only does that make it a competition to find the shortest url providing a complete list of OED words, but it also takes dozens of popular languages out of the competition as networking and HTTP requests aren't terribly common (or golfy) built-ins. Typically,  the dictionary is provided as input.

Comment: **2) Why restrict to upper-case only?** Some languages may handle mixed-case or lower-case better.